# How to insert nulls into a SQL Server table

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = [['Alex', 182.2],['Bob', 183.2],['Clarke', 188.4], ['Kelly', NA]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Height'])
```

I have the following SQL Server table:

```
create table dbo.heights as (
   name    varchar(10),
   height  float 
)
```

This is my code to upload the data to my table:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO dbo.heights(name, height) values (?, ?)', row.name, row.height)
    cnxn.commit()
cursor.close()
cnxn.close()
```

I want to upload the dataframe into my SQL Server table, but it fails on the null value. I tried replacing the NA with an `np.nan` value and it still failed. I also tried changing the height column to an "object" and replacing the NA with None and that also failed.

Comment: Perhaps try  ['Kelly', NULL]

Comment: The dataframe won't accept null because the height column is of the type float

Comment: did you try [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)?

Comment: Not yet, I'll give it a try

Comment: Have you tried `None` yet?

Comment: Like I mentioned in the post, I did try None and it did not work. It said that the SQLServer table can't accept none in a column of floats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following instead:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
     query = "INSERT INTO dbo.heights(name, height) values (?, ?)"
     data = [row.name, row.height]
     cursor.execute(query, data)
     cursor.commit()
```

Or use the following:

```
query = "INSERT INTO dbo.heights(name, height) values (?, ?)"
data = [row.name, row.height for index, row in df.iterrows()]
cursor.executemany(query, data)
cursor.commit()
```

You'll see your None values as None in Python and as NULL in your database.

Comment: What's the difference between what you did and what I did? I'd love to understand why your solution works

Comment: Your code is pretty fine and is regularly used. However, when you are dealing with Pandas data frames, a Null value is a NaN not None. If you pass it directly in the execution command, you will be passing a NaN, which would raise an error. If you use lists, your NaN becomes a None because you're no longer using the data frame. This should work without errors because a None in python equals a NULL in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried replacing the NA with an np.nan

Because in such case you have to first define dataframe schema and make it nullable float.

"By default, SeriesSchema/Column objects assume that values are not nullable. In order to accept null values, you need to explicitly specify nullable=True, or else you’ll get an error."

[Further Reading](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dataframe_schemas.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (`name`, `height`) VALUES (%s, %s)", (row.name, row.height))
    cnxn.commit()
cursor.close()
cnxn.close()
```